# I want replace exact word in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to replace exact word in mysql.

For example, I want to replace 'u' with 'you' in a sentence. 
sentence: are u sure.
output : are you sure.

I tried use replace but it is also changing 'u' in 'sure'. but i can't get the exact word to replace

Also i want change the cases where **u** like **"u, can"** , **"can u?"** , **"u"** , **"u r a beauty"** where every line is in each row of the database and column type is **TEXT**.

**I need update query.**

Comment: You want to check for word boundaries, you could use regular expressions to match that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: I tried the regex but there is error that regex replace doesn't exit. can u tell me how to do it.

Comment: how did you use it? probably a typo

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong parameter the replace format in this case  is not  `set columnname = replace(columnname,'you','u')`   but  `replace(columnname,'u','you')`
and you should also check for word  boundaries .. ' u '
and you could use also like

```
update table 
set columnname = replace(columnname,' u ',' you ') 
where columnname  like '% u %' ;
```

but if you have several cases the you should manage each case properly eg for `' u '` and  `' u,'`

```
update table 
set columnname = case when columnname  like '% u %'
                        then  replace(columnname,' u ',' you ') 
                      when columnname  like '% u,%'
                        then  replace(columnname,' u,',' you,') 
                 end
where columnname  like '% u %'
OR columnname  like '% u,%' ;
```

If you have mysql 8 you could use regexp_replace

```
 update table 
 set columnname = REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname,'[[:<:]]u[[:>:]]','you') 
 where columnname regexp '[[:<:]]u[[:>:]]';
```

..

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('test u tesp','[[:<:]]u[[:>:]]','you') 
from dual
where 'test u tesp' regexp '[[:<:]]u[[:>:]]';
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198068/discussion-on-answer-by-scaisedge-i-want-replace-exact-word-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact word you should include the spaces around the word. so rather than `replace(columnname,'you','u')` you use `replace(columnname,' you ',' u ')` That should cover the situation you described

> I tried use replace but it is also changing 'u' in 'sure'. but i can't get the exact word to replace